# Parsing result from WCF WebHttp Service

Tags: wcf, linq-to-xml

I have a very simple WCF service running which returns the following (from a basic new project) xml:

```
  <ArrayOfSampleItem xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/WcfRestService1" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
     <SampleItem>
         <Id>1</Id>
         <StringValue>Hello</StringValue>
     </SampleItem>
  </ArrayOfSampleItem>
```

I am then consuming this in a Windows Phone 7 app.  The result is coming back fine however I'm having problems parsing the xml.  This is the code I am using on the callback after completion of the request:

```
        XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Parse(e.Result);

        itemsFetched.ItemsSource = from item in xmlDoc.Descendants("SampleItem")
                                   select new Product()
                                              {
                                                  Id = item.Element("Id").Value,
                                                  StringValue = item.Element("StringValue").Value
                                              };
```

The collection is not populated with this, when I try adding the namespace:

```
        XNamespace web = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/WcfRestService1";

        XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Parse(e.Result);

        itemsFetched.ItemsSource = from item in xmlDoc.Descendants(web + "SampleItem")
```

The item is found but I get a null exception when it attempts to get the Id value.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the `xmlns="..."` puts the elements and all its descendants in the namespace so you need to use your `XNamespace` object `web` anywhere where you access elements:

```
XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Parse(e.Result);
XNamespace web = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/WcfRestService1";

itemsFetched.ItemsSource = from item in xmlDoc.Descendants(web + "SampleItem")
                           select new Product()
                                              {
                                                  Id = item.Element(web + "Id").Value,
                                                  StringValue = item.Element(web + "StringValue").Value
                                              };
```

Comment: Thank you so much Martin, I typically must have tried everything but that!